# error in mgo: result has no field or method

Tags: go, mgo

I have the following code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "labix.org/v2/mgo"
    "labix.org/v2/mgo/bson"
)

func insertEntry(j *map[string]interface{}, entry string) {
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(entry), j)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}

func main() {
    c1 := `{
    "mw" : 42.0922,
        "ΔfH°gas" : {
          "value" : 372.38,
          "units" : "kJ/mol"
        },
        "S°gas" : {
          "value" : 216.81,
          "units" : "J/mol×K"
        },
        "index" : [
          {"name" : "mw", "value" : 42.0922},
          {"name" : "ΔfH°gas", "value" : 372.38},
          {"name" : "S°gas", "value" : 216.81}
        ]
        }`

    c2 := `{
    "name": "silicon",
    "mw": 32.1173,
    "index": [
    {
        "name": "mw",
        "value": 32.1173
    }
    ]
    }`

    var m map[string]interface{}

    insertEntry(&m, c1)
    insertEntry(&m, c2)
    chemical := m["ΔfH°gas"].(map[string]interface{})
    fmt.Println("value: ", chemical["value"].(float64))
    fmt.Println("units: ", chemical["units"].(string))

    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()

    // Optional. Switch the session to a monotonic behavior.
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    c := session.DB("test").C("chemicals")
    err = c.Insert(&m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    result := &m
    err = c.Find(bson.M{"name": "silicon"}).One(&result)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(result)
    fmt.Println("mw:", result.mw)
}
```

and got the following error

```
$ go run chemeo.go
# command-line-arguments
./chemeo.go:78: result.mw undefined (type *map[string]interface {} has no field or method mw)
```

How could I print mw out?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`result` is a map[string], so you can access the value with `result["mw"]`. The value of this map entry will be of type `interface{}`, Go's most general type, so you will have to convert it to a float to use it. See [type conversions](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#conversions).

I never used mgo, but it seems it uses encoding/json under the hood. If so, you can define a [struct that matches the structure of your JSON](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) and encoding/json will be able to unmarshal mgo's response into it.

Comment: result["mw"] produced the following error: "./chemeo.go:78: invalid operation: result["mw"] (index of type *map[string]interface {})"

Comment: It's because result is not a map, but a pointer to map, sorry that I didn't read closely enough. You have to dereference it first: `(*result)["mw"]`. You can also assign the dereferenced value to a new variable for convenience: `result2 := *result`.

Comment: No worries. Thank you it is working. How does it come that result does not change the map? Or does result get the address from Find method where the query query is saved?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I never used mgo, but looking at the error message, I would probably try

```
fmt.Println("mw:", result["mw"])
```

Comment: result["mw"] produced the following error: "./chemeo.go:78: invalid operation: result["mw"] (index of type *map[string]interface {})"